# Water rests about half an inch over cup from inflow

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to do a still image with a glass cup that is being filled up with water from a pitcher. I set up the Domain (Big Box), I have a circle filled with Ngon as inflow and a glass cup I modeled from a UV Sphere. The whole simulation works great, but the water doesn't go into the glass. It hits the top like as if there is an invisible cube around the whole object. [image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!** Okay so how I was able to fix this issue was I simply removed the plane from the Fluid Simulation. Not sure why that solved the issue but it did.

Comment: The plane may have been set as a collision object by accident?